# Regular language to finite automaton

Tags: automata, regular-language, finite-automata

I am trying to tun the following regular language into a finite automata, but I am confused by the U (union) and I am unsure of how to approach this part of the expression.

The expression:
$$
L[01((0 \cup 11)11^*)^*0]
$$

Comment: Apologies - I have amended. The "U" is obviously for union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union is easy:
$$
(0 \cup 11)
$$
means both $0$ and $11$ are recognized. This means there exist transitions from the state $q_i$ before the opening parenthesis to the state $q_j$ after the closing parenthesis, one via accepting $0$ and another one via accepting $11$:
$$
\delta(q_i, 0) = q_j \\
\delta(q_i, 11) = q_j
$$

```
                                             0
                                           ____
                                          /    v

                                      q_i        q_j

                                          \____^ 

                                            11
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I now understand I can go between the two states in the union. Would you recommend a process for now translating this into a finite automata?

Comment: It depends a bit on what kind of automaton you work with. For example a DFA accepts symbols not words, so you would have an intermediate state $q_k$ on the lower path:  $\delta(q_i, 1) = q_k, \delta(q_k, 1) = q_j$.